# (Neo4j) Query does not display a graph

Tags: neo4j

I have a query that I am trying to execute. The query works, but there isn't an option to see this data in graph format. Instead the data is returned in table/text format.

When I simplify the query, the output is displayed in graph format - No idea why,

This is the query that is giving me the issue:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[hi:hasIdentity]->(i:Identity)
MATCH (j:Person)-[hi2:hasIdentity]->(i2:Identity)
MATCH (i)-[bl:Linked]->(i2)
WHERE NOT p=j
return DISTINCT(p.id), COUNT(DISTINCT(j))
LIMIT 5
```

Does anyone have any idea why that might be the case?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to return variables associated with nodes and/or relationships for it to display as a graph. As it is now you're returning properties of nodes `(p.id)`, probably integers or strings. Try this return instead:

```
...
RETURN p, COUNT(DISTINCT j)
LIMIT 5
```

By the way, DISTINCT isn't a function, no need for parenthesis, and when you have a RETURN or WITH that has an aggregation, you don't need to use DISTINCT for that line since the non-aggregation variables become distinct since they act as the grouping key for the aggregation.